# Web Workers support in browsers

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cross-browser, web-worker

All,

We were happily chugging along with web workers, content with side-lining any browser without web workers support, until today when we realised that Chrome doesn't support nested web workers & script import. [Link](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22723)

Has anyone detailed information about which browser (particularly IE10, FF, Chrome, Safari & Opera) has what level of Web Worker support, Im interested in following things in particular:

- Nested Web Workers support
- Import script support
- XMLHTTPRequest support

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The link to the bug (that I hope will be fixed in the future) for Chrome is http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31666

As for importScripts, XHR - It should work on Chrome/FF/Safari but I haven't check it on Opera and IE10.